# How to do high availability for a VM in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to configure high availability for a VM in GCP. Could not figure out how to do it.

Internal load balancer or external which option should be used.

Please help !!

Comment: For HA you'll need a cluster, right?

Comment: Hi Lukasz, We have only 2 instance in active and passive mode. Route table needs to point to the active interface's IP  and when failover happens it should get updated with the secondary instance's IP as next hop address.

Comment: My initial thought is that what you are looking for is a managed group ... see https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances.  Using this technology, you can declare a template of what your image should look like and from here, GCP will ensure to keep a managed number of them running.  You can set the instance count to be 1 and if that 1 fails, a new one will be started.  Thus you don't need active/passive ... you just need "1".

Comment: Thank you Kolban for the infromation but this is not how our solution works. For high availability we have 2 instances in active/standby mode. Both exchanges heartbeat between them. When 15 heartbeats are missed then active goes for failover and standby becomes active. Both instance will have different VIPs so for the traffic next hop address needs to be updated. This is what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The best option to achieve your goal would be adding [static routes](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/routes#custom-routes) with different [priorities](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/routes#individualroutes).

Configure the first route with a high priority (lower number) with the next hop as the Active instance. Then create a second route with a lower priority (Higher number) with the next hop as the passive instance.

When the Active instance stops responding, it will send the new traffic to the second route, which will go to the passive instance.

A Load balancer, no matters if Internal or External, will load the traffic between both instances, so it is not what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks Katie for the information. I hope you are referring to the option mentioned in  link - https://cloud.google.com/solutions/best-practices-floating-ip-addresses. The only concern with this approach is that the virtual/floating IP addresses need to be outside of the IP address space used by the VPC and those addresses are not managed by GCP. This also means that we need to use custom route advertisements to use those routes over VPN or Dedicated/Partner Interconnect. The failover needs two API calls or gcloud commands to move the IP address. Can you please let me know how to overcome this.

Comment: Since you said you have two VMs on GCP, I think Katie Sinatra's point is to manually set two static routes: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/routes#static-route-next-hops. The origin of both routes it's supposed to be the same (for instance, any packet that comes from a VPN/Interconnect), but different destiny (route 1 with Active VM and high priority, and route 2 with Passive VM and low priority). Packets coming from your VPN/Interconnect will be routed to the Active VM, and if this VM doesn't work, packets will be routed to 2nd route. No floating IP addresses on this solution.